# How to set Wordpress CPT Default Title to Post Meta

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to set the default post title of a custom post type to the post category with a space then the publish date. However I am getting an error. I have tried a number of different variations of this.

```
function add_default_podcast_title( $data, $postarr ) {
if($data['post_type'] == 'podcasts') {
    if(empty($data['post_title'])){
        $ashow = get_the_category();
        $publishdate = the_date('M j');
        $data['post_title'] = $ashow.' '.$publishdate;
    }
}
return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'add_default_podcast_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please describe your error that you're getting.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1102

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-includes/wp-db.php:1102) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) returns an array but in your callback function you're using that array as a string. That's why getting that error. Here's the simplified and fixed version of your code, I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
function add_default_podcast_title( $data, $postarr ) {
    if ( 'podcasts' === $data['post_type'] && empty( $data['post_title'] ) ) {
        $ashow = 'prefix';
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $publishdate = the_date( 'M j' );
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
            $first_category = current( $categories );
            $ashow = $first_category->name;
        }
        $data['post_title'] = $ashow . ' ' . $publishdate;
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'add_default_podcast_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That worked, just needed to add an ";" at the end of  $ashow = $first_category->name

Comment: Oops!

Good to hear that :)